# iOS xcode re-using tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Can anyone please explain how to re-use a tableview controller with different information for each button selected, see picture.

[image]

Basically what I would like is for a user to tap the select button which presents the appropriate table view populated with the data, choose an item then return back to the Symbol Browser and also have that "Select" button change to the users selection from the table view.

Each "Select" button will need to have different information in the tableview.

Can anybody provide me with links on this? Sorry I am still grasping objective-c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a property in tableviewcontroller.h

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) int viewLoadfor
```

initialise this property when you navigate to tableviewcontroller

and check the value of viewLoadfor in tableviewcontroller and load tableview according to that

eg.

```
if(viewloadfor == 1){
tableviewarray = @[@"hello",@"hello1"];
}
else if(viewloadfor == 2){
tableviewarray = @[@"bye",@"bye1"];
}
```